# Take picture with volume button

Tags: ios, mpvolumeview

I'm developing an app with some camera functionality and I'd like to use the volume buttons to take a picture (as the Apple Camera app does).

Using `MPVolumeView` and this snippet:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: -500, y: -500, width: 0, height: 0)
let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: rect)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.addSubview(volumeView)
```

and registering to `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification` notifications I'm able to intercept when the button is pressed and avoid showing the volume HUD.

This trick works **unless** the setting "Change with Buttons" in Settings > Sounds is on. In that case, I still get the notification, but the HUD will appear.

Any idea how to hide the HUD even when that setting is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know for sure that the **JPSVolumeButtonHandler** available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jpsim/JPSVolumeButtonHandler) can

> Hide the HUD typically displayed on volume button presses.

I found that the workaround solution is here but it's similar to your solution:

```
- (void)disableVolumeHUD 
{
    self.volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT, 0, 0)];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] addSubview:self.volumeView];
}
```

I suggest to look at this repository, it's works very well and I suppose reading the description also when

> the setting "Change with Buttons" in Settings > Sounds is on

Comment: Does it work even with the "Change with Buttons" setting on? I'll have a look at the repo later

Comment: sorry I don't know more and now I can't try

Comment: Apparently if I use that class it works. I wonder what's the missing bit in my code.

Comment: The three lines that you posted seems to be ok so you need to check the other lines in your code; maybe it's just a little mistake.